# Help with output impedance of a circuit

Tags: transistors, ltspice, impedance

We have to find the output impedance of the following circuit, where the output is the upper pin of R4. If I try to compute it with LTspice, I get about 55 Ohm, but whenever I try to work on it theoretically, I get 77 Ohm, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

For the theoretic approach, I replaced the BJT with the T-model. I've asked a few other people, and we all get about 75 Ohm, if we replace with the T-model.

[image]

Edit: For the LTspice simulation I used the following circuit, to compute output impedance:

[image]

Comment: I think the 2N2222 is the problem here. LTSpice would model the transistor as a real 2N2222 (with on resistance etc) if you pick that model. As you mentioned, replacing it with a T model would give an ideal impedance.

Comment: I thought of that too. But we have done numerous exercises using 2N2222, and in all of them, there was almost no difference between simulation and theoretical results. I don't know though, I'll look at it, and check for any any mistakes again.

Comment: And what value for \$\beta\$ did you use and \$V_{BE}\$ and \$I_E\$?

Comment: I'd like to see the methodology used to compute it with LTspice (with pictures showing the results you got and how you got them.) I'd also like to see how you applied the t-model to compute it by hand (what did you compute for \$r_e\$, for example, and how?)

Comment: I would recommend to replace the 2N2222 transistor model by a simple hybrid-\$\pi\$ arrangement whose values like \$\beta\$ and \$r_{\pi}\$ are those used in the numerical application.

Comment: When I tried to find it by hand, I basically did exactly the same as the answer below G36, and got the same result. For the LTspice part, I just uploaded a screenshot of the circuit I made. And for the output impedance, I just divided V1 with the current going through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a small-signal analysis to find the output impedance. We also recognize the bootstrap capacitor \$C_2\$.

But we are now interested in finding the output resistance.

[image]

After some further simplification, we get this equivalent circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqrAmQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can see that:

$$V_{O} = (\frac{I_E}{\beta +1}+I_{R_3})R_{sig} + I_E\: r_e$$

$$R_{OUT} = \frac{r_e (R_3 + R_{sig}) + \frac{R_3 R_{sig}}{\beta +1}}{R_B + r_e}||R_E$$

Now for your circuit, we need to find the quiescent current.

$$I_E = \frac{4.5V - 0.7V}{2k\Omega + \frac{20k\Omega}{\beta +1}} \approx 1.728mA...1.8mA $$ if we assume that \$\beta = 100..200\$

Thus now we can find \$r_e\$ we have \$r_e \approx \frac{26mV}{I_E} \approx 15\Omega...14\Omega \$

So, we have all we need to find output resistance.

\$R_E = R_1||R_2||R_4 \approx 1.67k\Omega\$

And

\$R_{out} \approx 117\Omega\$ for \$\beta = 100\$

Or

\$R_{out} \approx 74.2\Omega\$ for \$ \beta = 200\$

Comment: Ok, I did exactly the same for theoretic solution, and got the same numbers, so I must have made a mistake with the LTspice simulation I guess. I just short circuited the Us source, and added an ac test source, parallel to R4. Then for the Rout, I divided the test source voltage with its current. Is that the correct methodology???

Comment: It looks like your measurement is fine. My LTspice is sowing Rout at 1kHz = 73.216975ohm  So, where is the problem?

Comment: I get 55ohm at 1KHz, for the exact circuit and the command that you see above. Do you know where i could have made the mistake??

Comment: Try this model for 2N2222  .model 2N2222 NPN(IS=1E-14 VAF=100 BF=200 IKF=0.3 XTB=1.5 BR=3 CJC=8E-12 CJE=25E-12 TR=100E-9 TF=400E-12 ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 RB=10 RC=.3 RE=.2 Vceo=30 Icrating=800m mfg=NXP) Can you copy your model?

Comment: .model 2N2222 NPN(IS=1E-14 VAF=100 BF=200 IKF=0.3 XTB=1.5 BR=3 CJC=8E-12 CJE=25E-12 TR=100E-9 TF=400E-12 ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 RB=10 RC=.3 RE=.2 Vceo=30 Icrating=800m mfg=NXP)

Comment: Ok, from what I see you use the same model as me. But I see the error on your circuit diagram. You need to add the coupling capacitor between the emitter and the V1 voltage source. Because without this capacitor when LTspcie is calculating the DC operation point it treats AC source as a short circuit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That was the problem!